# Can not show rightBarButtonItem on ipad

Tags: ios5.1

This is my code :

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"RETURN" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];
navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
[anotherButton release];       
[IpadAppDelegate.stackController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the reason :

need change `navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;`

to: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;`